# Ubuntu 12.04 printer unavailable when connecting to wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, printing

I have a Xerox Phaser 4510 printer that works fine when I connected it by Ethernet in Ubuntu 12.04. However, when I switched to wifi, I cannot print even the test page though I can connect to the printer(ping is OK). By the way, it does work when I print on Windows 7, no matter I use wired or wireless network.

So did anyone experience this situation before? Is it caused by mis-configuration or just a bug of Ubuntu? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced this before, but here are some possibilities:

- **Your router is filtering the port required for printer communication**. Less likely because of the test case with your Windows test case, but still possibly worth a try. Perhaps look on Google for similar cases with communication issues pertaining to *your particular router*, but not necessarily to do with that printer or OS.
- **A firewall on your Ubuntu machine is blocking communication on the wireless network**. Especially in the case of Windows, security is usually increased over wireless communication versus wired, for obvious reasons.
- **The authentication method pertaining to your printer setup isn't compatible with Ubuntu's wireless management system**. Another unlikely possibility, but still one that could be considered. This could also be a driver-related problem for the printer and/or the computer's wireless chipset.

Some possible fixes:

- **Print a configuration details page using your printer's physical panel**. This will give you an idea of how it's configured, and possibly point out any mis-configured or conflicting settings.
- **Run `nmap <printer-ip>`**. This should give you an idea of the ports used by the printer, and will give you a listing of the protocols used by the printer. Note that if you run this on your wired network, and then compare it to the results when run on your wireless network, you might get a good idea of which ports cannot be accessed wirelessly. (Note that you'll usually have to run `sudo apt-get install nmap` on a stock system.
- **Run `/usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp` and `sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd`**. These will tell you whether your printer has been discovered by CUPS or system-config-printer, and other details.

If the suggestions above haven't helped you solve the problem, or you'd like more details (source of info): [DebuggingPrinterProblems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#Network_printer)